# JavaScript not working after AJAX call - AJAX tabs

Tags: javascript, ajax

I trying to make a submenu with the ability to change the page content without the refreshing, so I used AJAX tabs to call an external htm. The tabs are working, but I have a JavaScript inside my external htm which makes the white navigation arrows work, and also crossfades the content, which is not working. How do I fix this?

I am talking about this particular page - "Nick 101"
[www.adigitalgoodie.com/about.htm](http://adigitalgoodie.com/about.htm)

It is supposed to work like it does on the frontpage
[www.adigitalgoodie.com/index.htm](http://adigitalgoodie.com/index.htm)

This is the JavaScript inside the htm, fetched via AJAX, which isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.contentnavright').click(function(){
            $('.contenttext1').fadeOut();
            $('.contenttext2').fadeIn();
            $('.contentnavleft').css('opacity', '1');
            $('.contentnavleft').css('-moz-opacity', '1');
            $('.contentnavleft').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=100)');
            $('.contentnavright').css('opacity', '0');
            $('.contentnavright').css('-moz-opacity', '0');
            $('.contentnavright').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=0)')     
        });

        $('.contentnavleft').click(function(){
            $('.contenttext1').fadeIn();
            $('.contenttext2').fadeOut();
            $('.contentnavleft').css('opacity', '0');
            $('.contentnavleft').css('-moz-opacity', '0');
            $('.contentnavleft').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=0)');
            $('.contentnavright').css('opacity', '1');
            $('.contentnavright').css('-moz-opacity', '1');
            $('.contentnavright').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=100)')
        });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that script is same for all pages.
As such you can just put it in the main html, and use the live/on jquery approach:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".contentnavright", function(){whatever});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Or maybe I'm just doing it wrong. Must be the latter. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Put that code in a function, and call the function after your ajax request finish

Comment: Could you explain to me how to do this? Maybe include an example.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @A Digital Goodie posted another answer because write it in a comment is impossible :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.contentnavleft').click(myFunc);  

function myFunc(){
   $('.contenttext1').fadeIn();
   $('.contenttext2').fadeOut();
   $('.contentnavleft').css('opacity', '0');
   $('.contentnavleft').css('-moz-opacity', '0');
   $('.contentnavleft').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=0)');
   $('.contentnavright').css('opacity', '1');
   $('.contentnavright').css('-moz-opacity', '1');
   $('.contentnavright').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=100)')
}
```

then, when you finished your ajax request, you put `$('.contentnavleft').click(myFunc);` to bind again the function to the .contentnavleft element.

Comment: But where do I put this? I'm sorry. I'm kind of new at this. :(

Comment: Put `$('.contentnavleft').click(myFunc);` inside the $(body).onload() and the other code somewhere inside the script tag. And then again at the end of your ajax request, when it is processed

Comment: I don't seem to have this $(body).onload() - Where do I put this?
And how do I put the functions at the end of the ajax request?

Sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: You have to write: `$(body).onload(function(){$('.contentnavleft').click(myFunc);});`